# log shipping issue copy and restore jobs failed error access to the path is denied (mscorlib)

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, log-shipping

I have given access permission(sqlserveragent and mine) to the secondary folder
but still I am getting this error. 
sql server : Ntservice\msssqlserver
sql agent: domain\test

> Message 2016-04-21 12:00:31.48    Starting transaction log copy.
>   Secondary ID: 'bfa5d1ac-8c4c-4004-a1d1-27ab9a0bd6b4' 2016-04-21
>   12:00:31.49   Retrieving copy settings. Secondary ID:
>   'bfa5d1ac-8c4c-4004-a1d1-27ab9a0bd6b4' 2016-04-21
>   12:00:31.49   Retrieved copy settings. Primary Server: 'xxx', Primary
>   Database: 'ac5T', Backup Source Directory: '\xx\Primaryshared',
>   Backup Destination Directory: '\test\SecondaryShared', Last Copied
>   File: '' 2016-04-21 12:00:31.51 Copying log backup files.
>   Primary Server: 'CRYSTAL', Primary Database: 'ac5T', Backup Source
>   Directory: '\xxx\Primaryshared', Backup Destination Directory:
>   '\TEST\SecondaryShared' 2016-04-21 12:00:31.54   Copying log backup
>   file to temporary work file. Source:
>   '\xxx\Primaryshared\ac5T_20160421164404.trn', Destination:
>   '\TEST\SecondaryShared\ac5T_20160421164404.wrk' 2016-04-21
>   12:00:31.56   *** Error: Access to the path
>   '\TEST\SecondaryShared\ac5T_20160421164404.wrk' is denied.(mscorlib)
>
> ---

Comment: Shouldn't the path begin with double back slash?  \\TEST\SecondaryShared

Comment: So you are using a domain account  domain\test ? try giving this account local admin  to the host where '\TEST\SecondaryShared lives, and test. Permissions are tricky business. ACLs can be messed up too. sugested reading https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.07.securitywatch.aspx

Comment: unsure what you mean. make the sql server agen run on an AD account like "Adventureworks\myServiceAccount". otherwise you have to give permissions to the folder to the entire machine, by machine name. And is also harder to troubleshoot

Comment: test is the server name so I have included double slash, I have given  the permissions to domain\test account also. Is there any issue with service account of the server we are running under NTService

Comment: please go to SQL Server Configuration Manager and provide here exactly the account for SqlServer Agent. If it is NTServcie is NOT a domain account.

Comment: Network Service Account

The Network Service account is a built-in account that has more access to resources and objects than members of the Users group. Services that run as the Network Service account access network resources by using the credentials of the computer account in the format <domain_name>\<computer_name>$. The actual name of the account is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Network_Service

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. all the jobs are successful but the restore job is skipping the log backup file and it is showing a message that could not find a log backup file that could applied to the secondary database

Comment: ummm no. that error message is telling you that the Agent cannot copy the file to begin with. at least the error message that you are showing you. but maybe we dont have all the info in here

Comment: skipped log backup file. Secondary DB: '5T', File: 'F:\SecondaryShared\5T_20160422144001.trn' 2016-04-22 09:48:01.97 Could not find a log backup file that could be applied to secondary database '5T'. 2016-04-22 09:48:01.97 The restore operation was successful. Secondary Database: '5T', Number of log backup files restored: 0 2016-04-22 09:48:01.98 Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: '5T' 2016-04-22 09:48:01.98 The restore operation was successful. Secondary ID: '603bba1a-f150-4acf-a994-da5763fc0436'

Comment: sorry but i dont think we can help you further without the whole story/info. All I can tell you is that you need to fix file and folder permissions. and follow first advice: Test with an admin account. A real AD account, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

0

Copy job failed with the following message:

Error: Access to the path '\WIN-T97MHK9GED1\Primary' is denied.(mscorlib) ***

I changed the user account of SQL Server Agent service to .\Administrator on secondary server only. And it resolved the issue. Please see the screenshot:

[image]